# How to access iframe within sandboxed iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox

Within a sandboxed iframe with `sandbox="allow-scripts"`, if I dynamically create a new iframe using JS, I am not able to access it and receive the following error:
`DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

iframe.contentWindow.document.open();// throws error
```

Why is the newly generated iframe considered cross origin? And how can I create an iframe that I can access?
I cannot change the outer iframe sandbox properties.